# ubuntu 12.04 weird network problem - can not visit most websites after several hours

Tags: 12.04, networking

I have met this problem for quite a while(almost a year).

- When i fresh open the computer, everything is fine, i can visit any website i like
- however, after some time(12-24 hours), i can not visit most websites(yahoo,bing,ubuntu etc)
- if i reboot my computer, the problem disappears, but the same pattern repeats, that is, atfer 12-24 hours, i can not visit most website.

I am pretty sure that it's not the problem of my network or computer hardware, it's the problem of ubuntu os itself. Because:

- I tried to switch to windows and android, they don't have the problem.
- I checked my dns and switched it to google's dns service(8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4), still not working.
- my android phone and my laptop actually share the same wifi network and my phone don't have that problem

I searched this again and again, still can not find the right answer to solve it. And it seems that many people have encountered this problem.

Any one have the similar problem? How to get rid of it?

Comment: sounds like you're running bit-torrent or something and your router is choking.  a reboot forces your browser to refresh dns instead of accepting the stale unreachables and the router's table hasn't filled up with crap yet since torrents are still starting up/your connection count is low

Comment: No, I didn't use bit-torrent or transmission etc. I am pretty sure about this. I agree with you that it's somehow about the DNS.

Comment: you're sure you are using bit-torrent or you're not.  there is no pretty sure on app usage unless you are proxying a support request to AU.

Comment: I am not using any downloading software, i just use normal browsers(chrome firefox etc) to surf the web. And what is AU?

Comment: If you're just using vanilla and only a browser, the only thing I've seen this happen with is sites that open a ton of connections and the router choked, the fact that a pirating website was browsed and your connection is throttled, or the ISP/your DNS server is lagging... and wireless bugs.

Comment: What is really weird is that even if i don't touch anything the problem still appears. For example, I fresh open the ubuntu computer and just go to sleep, the next morning, i get up and open the browser and i can not visit almost any websites, i have to reboot.

Comment: Then it's a bug.  You should file a bug, not ask a question.